# upload multiple images at a time with paperclip using activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

i'm trying to allow myself to upload 5 images for each model using active admin but i can't seem to figure out how to do it. here is my activeadmin code so far:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Piece do
  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :description
      f.input :cost
      f.input :category
      f.input :photo, :as => :file, :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.photo.url(:medium))
    end
    f.buttons
  end

  index do
    column :id
    column :name
    column :cost
    column :category
    column :inventory_count
    column :available_count
    column :materials
    column :created_at
    default_actions
  end
end
```

how would I allow for 5 at a time instead of just 1?

Comment: In your Piece model definition, does it have_many :photos, or is photo attached to a Piece? You'll need to first get Piece to have_many photos.

Comment: it has_attached_file :photo. how would it look if i switched to has_many? how would that worK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how it'd work:

```
class Piece
  has_many :pictures
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
end

class Picture
  has_attached_file :photo
end
```

Then in your active admin form, you'd

```
f.has_many :pictures do |ff|
  ff.input :photo, as: :file, :hint => ff.template.image_tag(ff.object.photo.thumb.url)
  ff.input :_destroy, as: :boolean
end
```